# AOT: image '...dll.so' not found

Tags: c#, android, performance, xamarin, mono

I have simple android xamarin project that creating UI objects dynamically in code according to data which come from tcp server.

my project is working correctly. However, mobile app working too slow when I get first data from tcp. After receive first part of data from server I get this log :

> 07-24 10:38:57.964 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly Ref addref
>   MobileUI[0xae1b2f60] -> Newtonsoft.Json[0xae1b30e0]: 2 07-24
>   10:38:58.103 D/Mono    (28931): Image addref
>   System.Numerics[0x8ac19a40] -> System.Numerics.dll[0x89e73f00]: 2
>   07-24 10:38:58.103 D/Mono    (28931): Prepared to set up assembly
>   'System.Numerics' (System.Numerics.dll) 07-24 10:38:58.103 D/Mono
>   (28931): Assembly System.Numerics[0x8ac19a40] added to domain
>   RootDomain, ref_count=1 07-24 10:38:58.105 D/Mono    (28931): AOT:
>   image 'System.Numerics.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/mobilui.mobilui-esIhRaij7KzG50Md-AzKtg==/lib/x86/libaot-System.Numerics.dll.so"
>   not found 07-24 10:38:58.106 D/Mono    (28931): AOT: image
>   '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Numerics.dll.so' not found:
>   dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/mobilui.mobilui-esIhRaij7KzG50Md-AzKtg==/lib/x86/libaot-System.Numerics.dll.so"
>   not found 07-24 10:38:58.106 D/Mono    (28931): Config attempting to
>   parse: 'System.Numerics.dll.config'. 07-24 10:38:58.106 D/Mono
>   (28931): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Numerics/System.Numerics.config'.
>   07-24 10:38:58.106 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly Ref addref
>   netstandard[0xa67841e0] -> System.Numerics[0x8ac19a40]: 2 07-24
>   10:38:58.106 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly Ref addref
>   System.Numerics[0x8ac19a40] -> mscorlib[0xae1b22a0]: 47 Loaded
>   assembly: System.Numerics.dll [External] 07-24 10:38:58.306 D/Mono
>   (28931): Image addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x8ac19da0] ->
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0x89e73a00]: 2 07-24 10:38:58.306
>   D/Mono    (28931): Prepared to set up assembly
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization' (System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)
>   07-24 10:38:58.306 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly
>   System.Runtime.Serialization[0x8ac19da0] added to domain RootDomain,
>   ref_count=1 07-24 10:38:58.307 D/Mono    (28931): AOT: image
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed:
>   library
>   "/data/app/mobilui.mobilui-esIhRaij7KzG50Md-AzKtg==/lib/x86/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so"
>   not found 07-24 10:38:58.308 D/Mono    (28931): AOT: image
>   '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so'
>   not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/mobilui.mobilui-esIhRaij7KzG50Md-AzKtg==/lib/x86/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so"
>   not found 07-24 10:38:58.308 D/Mono    (28931): Config attempting to
>   parse: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.config'. 07-24 10:38:58.308
>   D/Mono    (28931): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization.config'.
>   07-24 10:38:58.309 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly Ref addref
>   netstandard[0xa67841e0] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0x8ac19da0]: 2
>   07-24 10:38:58.310 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly Ref addref
>   System.Runtime.Serialization[0x8ac19da0] -> mscorlib[0xae1b22a0]: 48
>   Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External] 07-24
>   10:38:58.347 D/Mono    (28931): Image addref System.Data[0x8ac19c80]
>   -> System.Data.dll[0x8bec7200]: 2 07-24 10:38:58.350 D/Mono    (28931): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Data' (System.Data.dll)
>   07-24 10:38:58.350 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly System.Data[0x8ac19c80]
>   added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1 07-24 10:38:58.351 D/Mono
>   (28931): AOT: image 'System.Data.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed:
>   library
>   "/data/app/mobilui.mobilui-esIhRaij7KzG50Md-AzKtg==/lib/x86/libaot-System.Data.dll.so"
>   not found 07-24 10:38:58.352 D/Mono    (28931): AOT: image
>   '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Data.dll.so' not found:
>   dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/mobilui.mobilui-esIhRaij7KzG50Md-AzKtg==/lib/x86/libaot-System.Data.dll.so"
>   not found 07-24 10:38:58.390 D/Mono    (28931): Config attempting to
>   parse: 'System.Data.dll.config'.Loaded assembly: System.Data.dll
>   [External]
>
> 07-24 10:38:58.390 D/Mono    (28931): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Data/System.Data.config'. 07-24
>   10:38:58.390 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly Ref addref
>   netstandard[0xa67841e0] -> System.Data[0x8ac19c80]: 2 07-24
>   10:38:58.392 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly Ref addref
>   System.Data[0x8ac19c80] -> mscorlib[0xae1b22a0]: 49 07-24 10:38:58.393
>   D/Mono    (28931): Assembly Ref addref System.Data[0x8ac19c80] ->
>   System.Xml[0xa4da4340]: 4 07-24 10:38:58.421 D/Mono    (28931):
>   Assembly Ref addref System.Data[0x8ac19c80] -> System[0xa4da3200]: 5
>   07-24 10:38:58.425 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly Ref addref
>   System.Data[0x8ac19c80] -> System.Core[0xae1b4820]: 7 07-24
>   10:38:59.038 D/Mono    (28931): Image addref
>   Microsoft.CSharp[0x8ac1ad00] -> Microsoft.CSharp.dll[0x89e74e00]: 2
>   Loaded assembly: Microsoft.CSharp.dll [External]07-24 10:38:59.038
>   D/Mono    (28931): Prepared to set up assembly 'Microsoft.CSharp'
>   (Microsoft.CSharp.dll)
>
> 07-24 10:38:59.038 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly
>   Microsoft.CSharp[0x8ac1ad00] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
>   07-24 10:38:59.040 D/Mono    (28931): AOT: image
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/mobilui.mobilui-esIhRaij7KzG50Md-AzKtg==/lib/x86/libaot-Microsoft.CSharp.dll.so"
>   not found 07-24 10:38:59.041 D/Mono    (28931): AOT: image
>   '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/Microsoft.CSharp.dll.so' not found:
>   dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/mobilui.mobilui-esIhRaij7KzG50Md-AzKtg==/lib/x86/libaot-Microsoft.CSharp.dll.so"
>   not found 07-24 10:38:59.041 D/Mono    (28931): Config attempting to
>   parse: 'Microsoft.CSharp.dll.config'. 07-24 10:38:59.041 D/Mono
>   (28931): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/Microsoft.CSharp/Microsoft.CSharp.config'.
>   07-24 10:38:59.041 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly Ref addref
>   MobileUI[0xae1b2f60] -> Microsoft.CSharp[0x8ac1ad00]: 2 07-24
>   10:38:59.041 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly Ref addref
>   Microsoft.CSharp[0x8ac1ad00] -> mscorlib[0xae1b22a0]: 50 07-24
>   10:38:59.042 D/Mono    (28931): Assembly Ref addref
>   Microsoft.CSharp[0x8ac1ad00] -> System.Core[0xae1b4820]: 8 07-24
>   10:39:00.594 W/zygote  (28931): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to
>   register 0 native methods for
>   md5c7e47b98fff270a788c54b9af169257b.ExtendedLabelRenderer 07-24
>   10:39:00.601 W/zygote  (28931): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to
>   register 0 native methods for
>   md5c7e47b98fff270a788c54b9af169257b.ExtendedEntryRenderer 07-24
>   10:39:00.610 I/zygote  (28931): Do partial code cache collection,
>   code=26KB, data=30KB 07-24 10:39:00.613 I/zygote  (28931): After code
>   cache collection, code=26KB, data=30KB 07-24 10:39:00.613 I/zygote 
>   (28931): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB 07-24 10:39:06.342
>   W/zygote  (28931): Checksum mismatch for dex base.apk

for example

```
AOT: image 'System.Numerics.dll.so' not found
```

why I get this log. Am I escape these not found issues ?

```
AOT: image 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found

AOT: image 'System.Data.dll.so' not found

AOT: image 'Microsoft.CSharp.dll.so' not found
```

somehow these 'not found' issues is handled by android itself. Can I handle these 'not found' issues in compile time ?

Comment: Mono is directory/ARCH probing to determine if native shared libraries are available, i.e. was the Xamarin.Android app AOT compiled and bundled.

Comment: so that I need to add these not found dlls to native shared libraries ?. thanks for your reply

Comment: If you compile the Xamarin.Android app with AOT enabled, the build process will do the work and AOT those IL-based assemblies and include them into your app bundle. (nothing is free of course and app size increases, but things like startup time decrease as the Mono runtime does not have to JIT those IL-assemblies thus saving CPU cycles during app startup). This might help: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-android-aot-works/

Comment: I'm trying your advise now. Thank you !

Comment: `<AotAssemblies>true</AotAssemblies>`
   ` <EnableLLVM>true</EnableLLVM>`
   `<BundleAssemblies>true</BundleAssemblies>`
I changed these 3 properties in android.csproj but not working. what you explain work in just release mode ? because I tried in debug mode.

Comment: when I try in release mode. I got conflicts error.

Comment: `...conflicts error....`  Maybe you should post a new question on what the problem is.