# Changing Entry Text change text in other Entry text in item of ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

UPDATED:

I've got a ListView that get items added by a button.
The items have this template:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewAlbaranFactura"
            Margin="10"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            HasUnevenRows="True">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame Margin="10" BackgroundColor="White">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                    <Button
                                        x:Name="BotonBorrarFacAlb"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="2"
                                        BackgroundColor="White"
                                        Clicked="BorrarItem"
                                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                                        Text="&#xf00d;">
                                        <Button.FontFamily>
                                            <OnPlatform
                                                x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                                                Android="fa-solid.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid"
                                                iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free" />
                                        </Button.FontFamily>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Label
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Text="Nro:" />
                                    <Label
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Text="Articulo:" />
                                    <Label
                                        Grid.Row="3"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Text="Relacion U/C:" />


                                    <Label
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                        Text="{Binding IdFacAlb}" />
                                    <Label
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                        Text="{Binding ArtFacAlb}"
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Start" />
                                    <Label
                                        Grid.Row="3"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                        Text="{Binding UnidadesCajaFacAlb}" />


                                </Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Text="{Binding Label1}" />
                                    <Label
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="2"
                                        Text="{Binding Label2}" />

                                    <Entry
                                        x:Name="NameUnidadesFacAlb"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Keyboard="Telephone"
                                        Text="{Binding UnidadesFacAlb}"
                                        />
                                    <Entry
                                        x:Name="NameCajasFacAlb"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="3"
                                        Keyboard="Telephone"
                                        Text="{Binding CajasFacAlb, StringFormat='{0:f2}'}"
                                         />

                                </Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="gridTotal">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Text="Precio: " />
                                    <Label
                                        x:Name="TotalFacAlb"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Text="{Binding TotalFacAlb, StringFormat='{0:F2} €'}" />

                                </Grid>

                                <Button
                                    BackgroundColor="Black"
                                    Clicked="btnGuardarAlbFac"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    Text="Guardar"
                                    TextColor="White" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

In my .CS i binding context to:

```
public AlbaranFactura (Modelos.Lite.Cabecera cabecera, Modelos.Lite.Cliente cliente)
    {
        this.cabecera = cabecera;
        this.cliente = cliente;
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.albaranFactura = new Controladores.AlbaranFacturaController(cabecera, ListViewAlbaranFactura, cliente);
        this.BindingContext = albaranFactura;
    }
```

And in `AlbaranFacturaController` :

```
public AlbaranFacturaController (Modelos.Lite.Cabecera cabecera, ListView ListViewAlbaranFactura, Modelos.Lite.Cliente cliente)
    {
        this.ListViewAlbaranFactura = ListViewAlbaranFactura;
        this.cliente = cliente;
        this.cabecera = cabecera;
        CargarAlbaranFactura();

        AddArticulo = new Command(abrir);
    }
```

Where `CargarAlbaranFactura()`load data:

```
public void CargarAlbaranFactura()
    {
        try
        {
            Utils.UIHandler.RunOnUI(() => {
                ListViewAlbaranFactura.BeginRefresh();
            });
            var NroCliente = cliente.CODIGO;
            var data = Conexiones.SQLiteHandler.GetSql(Connstring, "SELECT * FROM CabFacAlb;");
            Modelos.Lite.CabFacAlb cab = data.Select(q => SelectCabFacAlb(q)).Where(q => q.ClienteCFA == NroCliente).SingleOrDefault();
            var IdClienteTest = cab.NumCFA;
            var data2 = Conexiones.SQLiteHandler.GetSql(Connstring, "SELECT * FROM FacAlb;");
             List<Modelos.Lite.FacAlb> listadata2 = data2.Select(q => SelectFacAlb(q)).Where(q => q != null).ToList();

            var facalbList = new ObservableCollection<Modelos.Lite.FacAlb>();

            try
            {
                facalbList = new ObservableCollection<Modelos.Lite.FacAlb>(listadata2.Where(q => q != null && q.IdFacAlb == IdClienteTest ));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                facalbList = null;
            }

            foreach(var item in facalbList)
            {
                var relacion = item.UnidadesCajaFacAlb;
                if(relacion == 0)
                {
                    item.Label1 = "Kg :";
                    item.Label2 = "Ud :";
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Label1 = "Ud :";
                    item.Label2 = "Cajas :";
                }
            }
            Utils.UIHandler.RunOnUI(() => {
                this.ListViewAlbaranFactura.ItemsSource = null;
                this.ListViewAlbaranFactura.ItemsSource = facalbList;
                ListViewAlbaranFactura.EndRefresh();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utils.UIHandler.ErrorDebug("Cargar Albaran/factura: Warning", ex.Message, Utils.UIHandler.MessageLevel.Warning);
        }

    }
```

I don't understand how link directly the text from a entry in a item to the other entry text.

My items are `Modelos.Lite.FacAlb`where are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    public class FacAlb : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public long         IdContador { get; set; }
    public long         IdFacAlb { get; set; }
    public string       FechaFacAlb { get; set; }
    public string       TipoDocumento { get; set; }
    public string         ArtFacAlb { get; set; }
    public string unidadesFacAlb;
    public string cajasFacAlb;
    public string UnidadesFacAlb
    {
        get
        {
            return unidadesFacAlb;
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                if (value == unidadesFacAlb) return;
                unidadesFacAlb = value;
                if (UnidadesFacAlb != "")
                {
                    totalFacAlb = (PrecioFacAlb * double.Parse(UnidadesFacAlb))*((100-DtoFacAlb)/100);
                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error " + ex.Message);
            }

            SetCajas();
        }

    }
    public string CajasFacAlb
    {
        get
        {
            return cajasFacAlb;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == cajasFacAlb) return;
            cajasFacAlb = value;
            SetUnidades();
        }
    }
    public double?      UnidadesCajaFacAlb { get; set; }
    public double?      PrecioFacAlb { get; set; }
    public double?      DtoFacAlb { get; set; }
    public double?      totalFacAlb;
    public double?      TotalFacAlb
    {
        get
        {
            return totalFacAlb;
        }
        set
        {

            if (value == totalFacAlb) return;
            totalFacAlb = value;

        }
    }
    public string       Label1 { get; set; }
    public string       Label2 { get; set; }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    void SetCajas()
    {
        if(UnidadesCajaFacAlb != 0 && UnidadesCajaFacAlb != null && UnidadesFacAlb != "")
        {
            double? valor = double.Parse(UnidadesFacAlb) / UnidadesCajaFacAlb;

            if(valor != null)
            {
                CajasFacAlb = valor.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                CajasFacAlb = "";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            CajasFacAlb = "";
        }

    }
    void SetUnidades()
    {
        if(UnidadesCajaFacAlb != 0 && UnidadesCajaFacAlb != null && CajasFacAlb != "")
        {
            double? valor = double.Parse(CajasFacAlb) * UnidadesCajaFacAlb;
            if(valor != null)
            {
                UnidadesFacAlb = valor.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                UnidadesFacAlb = "";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            UnidadesFacAlb = "";
        }
    }

    public FacAlb() { }
    public FacAlb(Dictionary<string, object> q)
    {

        this.IdContador = (long)q["IdContador"];
        this.IdFacAlb = (long)q["IdFacAlb"];
        this.FechaFacAlb = q["FechaFacAlb"] as string;
        this.TipoDocumento = (string)q["TipoDocumento"];
        this.ArtFacAlb = (string)q["ArtFacAlb"];
        this.PrecioFacAlb = double.Parse(q["PrecioFacAlb"].ToString());
        this.DtoFacAlb = (double?)q["DtoFacAlb"];
        this.UnidadesCajaFacAlb = q["UnidadesCajaFacAlb"] is DBNull ? 0 : (double?)q["UnidadesCajaFacAlb"];
        this.UnidadesFacAlb = q["UnidadesFacAlb"].ToString();
        this.CajasFacAlb = q["CajasFacAlb"].ToString();

    }

}
```

How i build the MVVM function that control the PropertyChanged ?

Comment: This is completely the wrong approach to take.  Each row in your List is bound to a model.  Any changes made should be reflected in that model.  You should not try to interact with the UI elements directly in code - instead, you should use the values in the model that are bound to each UI element.

Comment: @Jason so, how i make the interaction in the model instead making changes directly with UI elements?

Comment: there are extensive documentation and sample apps that demonstrate how to use databinding

Comment: I don't understand what is the `BindingContext` of your items... Could you update your post to show us your `ListView` items source ?
As a global rule you shoudn't at the same time, bind Text to a context property AND use TextChanged, it defeats the purpose of binding.

Comment: @Roubachof ItemSource from the ListView are `{Modelos.Lite.FacAlb}`

So i understand that i souldn't use TextChanged if i am using binding for set the Text for Entry, but how i implement that operations for Entry for my models.

Comment: @Jason  i have updated the question as i think the MVVM should works but don't know if i'm in the right way.

Comment: Where are your TextChanged events?

Comment: @Jason Forgot to update title, know i don't use textChanged, i will use the MVVM model to implement those changes.

Comment: Your entries still have them, thats why I asked.  More generally I’m trying to understand what sort of changes are supposed to happen in your model.  The short answer is to use the setters on properties to trigger whatever other changes need to happen elsewhere in the model.

Comment: @Jason deleted, thanks.
The changes that i need is, that when for example i enter in NameUnidadesFacAlb`` a '1', in `NameCajasFacAlb`Text changes to: `NameUnidadesFacAlb / UnidadesCajaFacAlb`
And in the other way, if change `NameCajasFacAlb`it change `NameUnidadesFacAlb`with `NameCajasFacAlb * UnidadesCajaFacAlb `.
How i implement these in the setter on properties?

Comment: what does `Controlador` look like (i guess that's your ViewModel even though you call it Controller)? in MVVM you'd typically have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call `PropertyChanged` in your setters.

Comment: @MarkusDresch Yep, this is a MVVM , i delete that `Controlador`, sorry.
But how i implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the setters?

Comment: you may want to check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm - there are a few examples on viewmodels with INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: almost there. now you simply call `NotifyPropertyChanged` in all setters that are bound to the UI.

Comment: @MarkusDresch i update the FacAlb.cs as i understand how INotifyPropertyChanged works, but when i try to add an item to the ListView the debug crash -> https://pastebin.com/2jk20FxV

Comment: that does not look like a related problem. it says `08-16 09:28:48.549 D/Mono    ( 5040): AOT: image 'System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.SGesRepartidores-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.so" not found`. maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505062/aot-image-dll-so-not-found ?

Comment: @MarkusDresch dunno if it's the correct track debug line, but it's related, because it crash when i set the `set`and `get` for `UnidadesFacAlb`, if i use with `{ get; set; }` it works.

Comment: well, strange. can you try to run it without AOT?

Comment: ah... also make sure `valor` is not null before calling `ToString()` on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198029/discussion-between-ntzz-and-markus-dresch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `INotifyPropertyChanged` in **FacAlb** , set/get of parameters can be writtren as follow:

**FacAlb**:

```
public class FacAlb : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

private long idContador;
public long IdContador 
{
   set
   {
      if (idContador != value)
      {
         idContador = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("IdContador");
      }
    }
    get
    {
         return idContador;
    }
}

private long idFacAlb;
public long IdFacAlb 
{
   set
   {
      if (idFacAlb != value)
      {
         idFacAlb = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("IdFacAlb");
      }
    }
    get
    {
         return idFacAlb;
    }
}

privatestring fechaFacAlb;
public string FechaFacAlb 
{
   set
   {
      if (fechaFacAlb != value)
      {
         fechaFacAlb = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("FechaFacAlb");
      }
    }
    get
    {
         return fechaFacAlb;
    }
}

private string TipoDocumento;
public string tipoDocumento 
{
   set
   {
      if (tipoDocumento != value)
      {
         tipoDocumento = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("TipoDocumento");
      }
    }
    get
    {
         return tipoDocumento;
    }
}

private string artFacAlb;
public string ArtFacAlb 
{
   set
   {
      if (artFacAlb != value)
      {
         artFacAlb = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("ArtFacAlb");
      }
    }
    get
    {
         return artFacAlb;
    }
}
//... other code

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

//... other code

}
```

Here is [a official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm#interactive-mvvm) , and a discussion about [using INotifyPropertyChanged in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667408/how-to-implement-inotifypropertychanged-in-xamarin-forms).

Comment: Thanks, this is clear, but there's one question more, i have updated the question, as u can see. I want to see the changes applied in the front in the ListView, so, i think i should apply the `PropertyChanged` in my ModelView too? How?

Comment: @ntzz Yeah , each property in listview's model need to be auto changed should apply the `propertyChanged` .You just need to do is add `OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName");` in the `set` method of property.

Comment: @ntzz If the number of items in the list view has changed, you can reload the listview data after the data update.

Comment: Thanks! i will have a look at documentation to understand all. Thanks for all.
Also thanks to @Jason and Markus, they both help me too :)

Comment: @ntzz Great. Here is an article about Consuming a RESTful Web Service .This way also can update listview .You also can have a look at this. If problems you can update here ,I will check it.